# Make images automatically accessible to chrome in PC

Tags: sync, chrome-for-android, photos, instant-upload, auto-upload

I have the following use case:

1. Make photo with Android phone
2. Use that photo in a web application in Chrome, in my PC, by clicking on the button "attach file" which opens a file browser.

I want to avoid being force to send anything anywhere. I just want to click the "attach file" button in the web page and be able to select the photo that I just made with my phone.

Currently my workflow is a nightmare:

1. Make photo
2. Send it from my phone with WhatsApp, on a chat with myself
3. Go to my computer, to the https://web.whatsapp.com tab
4. Open the chat with myself
5. Download the photo to my computer
6. Go to the webpage where I want to access the photo.

Instead of WhatsApp I could use email or any other sharing mechanism. It would still be a pita.

I have sync setup in my Chrome for Android, so that passwords and so on are automatically shared. Can I do something similar with photos?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be Dropbox. The Dropbox app for Android includes an option to auto-upload photos to your Dropbox storage in the cloud. Then, if you also have Dropbox installed on your PC, they'll be automatically synced to the Dropbox folder on your PC. You can select them from the file upload dialog in Chrome, or drag-and-drop them from an Explorer window into Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options that match this use case. Dropbox doesn't match it directly, and Google Photos somewhat. Google Photos would allow you to click the attach file button, and attach files, if you are using a Google App.

**Dropbox**.

1. Download the Dropbox app for Android [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android).
2. Download Dropbox for PC [here](http://dropbox.com/download).
3. Allow time for your phone to sync with Dropbox on PC.

You can select your files from the file upload dialog in Chrome, or drag-and-drop them from the File Explorer window into Chrome.

**Google Photos**

1. Download the Google Photos app for Android here. (Sorry, stack overflow says that because of my current reputation, I can't post more than 2 links. The app is pretty easy to find though, just search "Google Photos" in the play store.)
2. On your PC, go to photos.google.com
3. Click the photo you want to download, and click on the three dots in the top right corner
4. Click "Download".

**Pros & Cons**

*Dropbox-*

Pro- Automatically synced with your computer.

Con- Only 2GB of storage for photos.

Pro- App is easy to use.

*Google Photos*-

Pro- Automatically synced with your computer

Pro- No download needed for PC, just go onto the webpage

Pro- "Unlimited" Storage (15GB of free storage for original files, then unlimited storage for files compressed by Google's Algorithm)

Pro- Search through your photos with photo recognition. You can search photos for specific people, items, places, ect, ect.

Overall:

My personal choice would to use Google Photos, and I would recommend this for your work, since you use Google Chrome. Dropbox is a good option though.